# How do I separate events into different sections of a list based on a date in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, list, foreach, swiftui

I am using JSON data that provides all U.S. holidays in 2019. The data give me access to a name, description, and date. I imported everything successfully, but want to list the holidays out in sections based on the month.

In SwiftUI, The code would go: List -> ForEach -> Section -> ForEach -> ListRow, but I am not sure how to say if the date's months match put them in the same section. I may be going about it the wrong way...

The **allHolidays** represents the holiday data I have:

```swift
List {
    ForEach(?) { month in
        Section(header: Text("Month goes here...")) {
            ForEach(self.allHolidays, id: \.name) { holiday in
                HolidayRowView(name: holiday.name, date: holiday.date)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have all the holidays list out with dates below them. I can not get them to split into separate sections.

Here is a snippet of the JSON Data from Calendarific:

```swift
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200
    },
    "response": {
        "holidays": [
            {
                "name": "Name of holiday goes here",
                "description": "Description of holiday goes here",
                "date": {
                    "iso": "2018-12-31",
                    "datetime": {
                        "year": 2018,
                        "month": 12,
                        "day": 31
                    }
                },
                "type": [
                    "Type of Observance goes here"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit your question to include your holiday data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first `ForEach` you need to iterate over all the months. `Calendar` will give you a list of localised names for months, so you can use it as your section title. In your inner `ForEach` you need to iterate over holidays that take place in a given month (section's title) so you have to filter your list:

```
private let calendar = Calendar.current

var body: some View {
   List {
        ForEach(1...12, id: \.self) { month in
            Section(header: Text(calendar.monthSymbols[month-1])) {
                ForEach(self.allHolidays.filter({
                        calendar.component(.month, from: $0.date) == month }),
                        id: \.name) { holiday in
                    HolidayRowView(name: holiday.name,
                                   date: holiday.date)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using filter was the solution, thank you! Had to make a few changes to adjust to the JSON data I was recieving, but it worked great.